# PowerBI api getting all reports - contact owner : I can only see the infos or workspace-report that my SPN has access

Tags: powershell, api, rest, powerbi, azure-service-principal

Im taking a chance after searching hours on the Microsoft website and in the examples script.
Is there anyone familiar with:

https://wabi-us-north-central-d-primary-redirect.analysis.windows.net/metadata/reports/$reportId/contacts.

I am looking to use that to fetch all reports in workspaces. --> Contact owner infos.

I was able to get that to works with 2 APIS

```
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Verbose -Url "https://wabi-us-north-central-d-primary-redirect.analysis.windows.net/metadata/reports/$reported/" -Method Get
```

```
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Verbose -Url "https://wabi-us-north-central-d-primary-redirect.analysis.windows.net/metadata/reports/$reportId/contacts" -Method Get
```

The issue I am having is that I can only get the workspaces-reports that I am part of it. I do have a SPN with all api permission for PowerBi Service, with also Tenant.ReadAll but not success.

If anyone was able to get further with this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now, make sure to add the **SPN as the member of the group**:

[image]

Enable **`Allow service principals to use read-only admin APIs`** add the security group in PowerBi Admin Portal

[image]

To resolve the issue, try assigning **`Workspace.ReadAll`** to get all the access to all the workspaces.

```
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/reports -Method Get 

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Verbose -Url "http://xxx-redirect.analysis.windows.net/v1.0/myorg/admin/metadata/reports" -Method Get
```

[image]

And then try executing the same for contacts,

```
 Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Verbose -Url "https://xxx/metadata/reports/$reportId/contacts" -Method Get
```

***If still the issue persists***, while getting all the workspaces-reports assign **`Report.Read.All`** API permission to the SPN.

- You can also try assigning **`Power BI Administrator`** role to the Azure AD Application like below:

[image]

Comment: Yes Thanks for all that infos! It was already all setup like this BUT not having the PowerBI Administrator role. That was my last chance ;) Did you see that: within all command with api/admin, you got an error 401 Unauthorized by using your SPN? It is all working good with my mfcgd admin WHO HAS PowerBI Administrator.. Thanks again!